# Client says they want Unreal scene viewable in a web browser  last minute

Tags: unreal, webgl, browser-based-games, web, unreal-5

I have a job that I did for a client and the client wants the project to be viewable in a web browser. I looked into it and all I found was people telling me that it's impossible, but this is a low resource demanding scene. It's not very computationally intensive. I noticed that I can package this for Android, iOS, Linux, and TVOS (which I think is an operating system for Apple TV?) and other targets that are possibly just a low powered as a web browser. Is there ANYTHING or ANYONE that can help me with this...? I've been directed to resources like:

https://nevercenter.com/silo/ (Milo in particular) which renders with Unreal technology but I can't find a tutorial on how to import an unreal project.

https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/gltf-exporter It appears to not work in my Unreal editor because I followed the docs and there is not export type as gltb.

https://github.com/ue4plugins/GLTFWebViewer This only works in certain versions of Unreal Engine 4.

So as you can see, nothing I found worked...

So how can I do this? Can someone please show me a way to package this project for a webpage?

Comment: Package the project for HTML5.

Comment: Can you do this in the Unreal 5 editor?

Comment: I have not tried in 5, it may be an experimental plug-in that needs to be enabled, but I know it is there and available.

Comment: Really? I can't find it https://imgur.com/a/4IbS6mA. Is there an experimental plugin? Please send a link.

Comment: I will give you a proper response tomorrow, when I can check, I know the new features will not be supported, Nanite, Lumen, Chaos... It is possible it was not brought forward yet due to these restrictions. If that is the case I recommend moving to 4.27 where HTML5 is a supported option.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could get some info on a plugin for Unreal 5. I don't know if I could port it to Unreal 4.27 at this point

Comment: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/pixel-streaming-in-unreal-engine/ if the client just wants to watch, this might work